# Create new Database microservice in AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, terraform

I need help on how to create new database microservice for docs metadata . My understanding of this task is to set-up some serverless databases using Aurora and DynamoDB in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [RDS Aurora Cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster) resource and here is the [DynamoDB terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table)